# How do I calculate a factorial for a specific amount of iterations in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to calculate a factorial for the number 56 for only 5 times, such that my answer should be = 458,377,920; where the factorial looks like this:
56 x 55 x 54 x 53 x 52 = 458,377,920.

my current code looks like the following and it is not working:

```
def my_factorial(n, b):
   count = 1
   vlue = n
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       while b > count:               
           for i in range(b):
               vlue = vlue * (vlue - 1)
               b -= 1
               print(vlue)
       return vlue

my_factorial(56, 5)
```

the results are not as expected:

```
3080
9483320
89933348739080
8088007215424892292570507320
65415860716765120080996841652938441974495741189603075080
```

Comment: btw this is called a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Comment: @wjandrea... Thanks for the formula reference.  I missed a crucial part of the falling factorial formula, which refers to the starting value of "n" and its required decrease by 1 each time the for loop runs.  This happens in two places in the loop, first in the multiplication and the other (either before or after the multiplication) to prepare the next for loop step.  Both user2272821 and Josh J pointed out this missing step, which when applied generated the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def my_factorial(n, b):
   vlue = n
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       for _ in range(b):
            vlue = vlue * (n - 1)
            n = n - 1
       return vlue

print(my_factorial(56, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

The body of the loop never decrement or used n

```
n -= 1
vlue = vlue * n
b -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I rewrote the function from the ground up, as an exercise.

```
def falling_factorial(n, b):
    """
    Return the product of n..n-b+1.

    >>> falling_factorial(4, 2)  # 4*3
    12
    >>> falling_factorial(5, 3)  # 5*4*3
    60
    >>> falling_factorial(56, 1)
    56
    >>> falling_factorial(56, 0)
    1
    """
    r = 1  # Running product
    for i in range(n, n-b, -1):
        r *= i
    return r
```

Usage:

```
>>> falling_factorial(56, 5)
458377920
```